# IntelliJ - Java Main Class is missing when I create a new project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have just started learning Java using an online course.
When I create a new project with IntelliJ, I don't have the `Main` class in the `src` folder. However, the instructor is saying IntelliJ should create the class "Main" by default.

HOW I SHOULD HAVE IT:

```
-"Name of the project"
  -Idea
  -src
      -"com.myname"
          -Main (the Class)
```

HOW I HAVE IT:

```
-"Name of the project"
  -Idea
  -src (which contains nothing)
```

Therefore, I have to create manually the class "Main" by clicking on "src" and creating a class named "Main" with this code inside:

```
Public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

}
```

**MY QUESTION:** how can I set IntelliJ to automatically create the `main` class every-time a new create a new project?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: FYI, eventually you may want to learn about defining your project with [*Apache Maven*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven). Maven is supported directly by all of the Big Three IDEs (IntelliJ, NetBeans, Eclipse).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the project from template:

[image: template]

**Command Line App** will add a class with the empty `main` method.